# Tag synonyms for emacsclient

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed some inconsistencies in the way the [server](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) tag is being used, sometimes in reference to using Emacs as an `edit-server`, and sometimes in reference to other kinds of servers. It also may be redundant to have tags for [emacsclient](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacsclient) and [emacs-daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-daemon), since the second implies the first. I don't have enough rep to suggest these changes directly in the tag wiki, so I'm requesting them here:

- [emacs-server](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-server) be added as a synonym for [emacs-daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-daemon), so we can indicate when a question is related to the Emacs server, and so those questions get linked to [emacs-daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-daemon) questions
- and possibly both of these get added as synonyms to [emacsclient](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacsclient), any question on one of these topics is almost certainly going to apply to all three

I'm not sure how tags and synonyms work in practice, so perhaps these aren't all synonyms; if not, their wikis should at least reference each other.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with this suggestion of making them synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the lists of questions tagged [emacsclient](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacsclient), [server](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server), [emacs-daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-daemon) and [daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daemon):

- The tags [daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daemon) and [emacs-daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-daemon) are clearly used interchangeably. There was only one question tagged [daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daemon) that wasn't about running Emacs as a daemon (it was [about `gnus-demon`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26723/gnus-doesnt-periodically-check-emails)). I'd have merged the tag except [there's something strange going on around these tags](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/498/a-daemon-in-invisible-chains).
- [server](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) and [daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daemon) have some overlap. However many of the questions tagged [daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daemon) do not apply to running an Emacs server in general, they're specifically about starting Emacs without a GUI. Therefore I disagree with synonymizing [daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daemon)=[emacs-daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-daemon) with [server](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server).
  By the way, I reviewed [server](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) and found that it is overwhelmingly about the Emacs server. I retagged two questions that are about other kinds of servers [1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31731/collaborative-editingusing-rudel-to-connect-to-a-gobby-process) [2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38282/cant-get-emacs-ycmd-to-work-valueerror-file-is-invalid).
- [emacsclient](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacsclient) and [server](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) have a lot of overlap. However [server](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) tends to focus on the server side (how to start a server, how to configure it) while [emacsclient](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacsclient) tends to focus on the `emacsclient` utility (e.g. its command line) and how to use it to open files and pop up windows (which does often involve server-side configuration). The differences are sufficiently marked that I don't think the tags should be synonyms. We should work out a policy for when to use each of them.

Note that synonyms are two-way. You can't have something like “if it's tagged [daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daemon) then it automatically shows up when searching for [server](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server).”