# A daemon in invisible chains

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms

When I try to propose the synonym [daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daemon) for [emacs-daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-daemon) by entering `daemon` on the [synonyms page for `'emacs-daemon`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/emacs-daemon/synonyms), it fails with the following error message:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> A synonym from daemon to emacs-daemon exists, chains are not allowed

But [daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daemon) is not in any [existing or proposed synonym](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=master). I don't see why I couldn't propose the synonym (other than a lack of tag score, but I'm a moderator).

Comment: I can confirm: I get the same message, and I also cannot propose a synonym.